# iOS Framework not able to create object

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have created a iOS framework in which I only have a UIView Class (**let say X**) in which I have declared some datasource and delegate methods.

1. Now when I am using the framework in a project and try to create a object of **X**, it gives me following error:

   ```
   Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_X", referenced from:
   objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
   ```
2. Now if I take a UIView in XIB and change its class to **X** and connect it to an outlet and then setDelegate and setDatasource it throws an exception:

   ```
   Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', 
   reason: '-[UIView setDataSource:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x756f670
   ```

if I don't do the above two steps. it builds and runs fine.

I hope I am clear with question. Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for 1:

The reason is that the framework is not built for the iPhone Simulator.  I had a similar issue with CocosDenshion, documented in this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15033433/how-to-archive-for-both-ios-devices-and-iphone-simulator) of mine (someone didn't like it though, for some reason).

The easiest solution is put your project and your framework into an Xcode Workspace and Xcode will build the framework for the iPhone Simulator as and when required.  If you don't want to do that then follow the instructions in the SO question linked above.

As for 2:

You need to provide the methods specified; it looks like you changed a `UITableView`-based class and changed it to a `UIView`-based class, which won't work.  Derive the new class from `UITableView` and things should start rolling again.

Comment: its an simple UIView class where I am creating a pie chart based on datasource from the users. It works absolutely fine when i am using the class directly but when I make a framework of that class these problem arise.

Comment: @Developer_Mario So where does the need for `setDataSource` come into it?

Comment: I had declared a protocol in my UIView class to take dynamic inputs from the user for the piechart (like tableview cellForRow). But the Problem is solved now as i have created a separate Protocol header to declare the datasource and delegate methods. I hope I made myself clear..    Thanks trojanfoe.. :)